# Creating Custom Widget Gtk2/C?

Tags: c, widget, gtk

i am following a book (Foundation of Gtk+) and when i compile these files :

http://pastebin.com/LagSdYwF

http://pastebin.com/0wNV6Feb

http://pastebin.com/iK0cfMY6

the terminal output this (gcc ipaddresstest.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0))  :

> ipaddresstest.c :(. text + 0xC9): undefined reference to
>   "my_ip_address_new"
>
> ipaddresstest.c :(. text + 0xD2): undefined reference to
>   "my_ip_address_get_type"
>
> ipaddresstest.c :(. text + 0xF6): undefined reference to
>   "my_ip_address_set_address"
>
> /tmp/cclTaXSL.o: in "ip_address_changed" function:
>
> ipaddresstest.c :(. text + 0x183): undefined reference to
>   "my_ip_address_get_address"
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

i didn't find nothing about this.
Where is the mistake?

PS: can you tell me about guide of this argument for gtk3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing symbols which cannot be resolved. Could it be because you have no mention of myipaddress.c, which has the function definitions, when you are invoking gcc?

Comment: gcc ipaddresstest.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0)

Comment: Sorry, how can i block handler in gtk3? in gtk2 i used gtk_signal_handler_block_by_data(G_OBJECT(obj),widget);

Comment: @Pegasum, sorry I'm not knowledgeable of GTK, so I can't answer.